# Unable to run CameraView on next activity on android studios

Tags: java, android, android-activity, camera

Im pretty new to android programming hence I need some help. When I run the program, it is only able to display the 1st page(IP address keying in page) and when I click the connect button, It is unable to run the next activity

I have added the 3 relevant Manifest for the camera permission & hardware usage.

I would like the User to key in the IP Address (which will be checked against the matcher) and if it matches, It will lead to the next activity which is the camera. I have tried to individually run the IP Address matcher and the Camera on 2 different projects and they work perfectly fine.

On the side note, at times I keep getting this NullPointerException which I think I was able to fix using the if statements for my OnclickListener and the addView ones in the MainActivity Class

This is my MainActivity Class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

private EditText ipAddr;
private String ipAddress;
private static final String IPADDRESS_PATTERN =
        "^([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +
                "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +
                "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +
                "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])$";

private Camera mCamera = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button connectButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connectButton);
    ipAddr = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ipAddr);

    if (connectButton != null) {
        connectButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                ipAddress = ipAddr.getText().toString();

                if(checkIpAddressFormat(ipAddress))
                {
                    Intent changePageIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,CameraView.class);
                    startActivity(changePageIntent);
                    Log.d("ERROR","Able to go next class");
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "This is an invalid IP", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });
    }
    try
    {
        mCamera = Camera.open();
        Log.d("ERROR","get camera");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.d("ERROR","Failed to get camera" + e.getMessage());
    }

    if(mCamera !=null)
    {
        CameraView mCameraView = new CameraView(MainActivity.this, mCamera);
        FrameLayout camera_view = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.camera_view);
        if (camera_view != null) {
            camera_view.addView(mCameraView);
        }
        Log.d("ERROR","ABLE TO PREVIEW camera" );
    }

}


private boolean checkIpAddressFormat(String qducIpAddress)  // using a method called checkIpAddressFormat and using string qducIpAddress
{
    boolean checkIpAddressFormatResult = false;
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(IPADDRESS_PATTERN);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(qducIpAddress);
    checkIpAddressFormatResult = matcher.matches();

    return checkIpAddressFormatResult;
}


}
```

CameraView Class

```
public class CameraView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
{
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;
public CameraView(Context context, Camera camera)
{
    super(context);
    mCamera = camera;
    mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
    mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_HARDWARE);
}


@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder)
{
    try
    {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
        mCamera.startPreview();
        Log.d("ERROR", "GOOD");
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        Log.d("ERROR","Camera error on surfaceCreated"+ e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int format, int width, int height)
{
    if (mHolder.getSurface() == null)
        return;

    mCamera.stopPreview();

    try
    {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        Log.d("ERROR","Camera error on SurfaceChanged" + e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder)
{
    mCamera.stopPreview();
    mCamera.release();
}
}
```

the following is my Logcat

```
01-01 18:35:09.773 15622-15622/? D/AndroidRuntime: >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
01-01 18:35:09.773 15622-15622/? D/AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is ON
01-01 18:35:09.988 15622-15622/? I/ethernet: Loading ethernet jni class
01-01 18:35:10.047 15622-15622/? D/AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm

                                                   --------- beginning of /dev/log/system
01-01 18:35:10.070 1415-1433/system_process W/ActivityManager: No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/com.video.newfirstworkingapp
01-01 18:35:10.808 1415-1433/system_process W/ActivityManager: No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/com.video.newfirstworkingapp
01-01 18:35:10.898 1415-1417/system_process D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 383K, 13% free 10545K/12103K, paused 2ms+3ms
01-01 18:35:10.941 1415-1433/system_process D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 99K, 14% free 10507K/12103K, paused 42ms
01-01 18:35:10.996 1415-1433/system_process D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 86K, 14% free 10514K/12103K, paused 37ms
01-01 18:35:11.093 1415-1433/system_process D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 211K, 12% free 10754K/12103K, paused 39ms
01-01 18:35:11.386 1415-1417/system_process D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 637K, 11% free 10872K/12103K, paused 3ms+3ms
01-01 18:35:11.492 1415-1417/system_process D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 698K, 11% free 10870K/12103K, paused 3ms+3ms
01-01 18:35:11.601 1415-1417/system_process D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 701K, 11% free 10874K/12103K, paused 3ms+3ms
01-01 18:35:11.707 1415-1417/system_process D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 700K, 11% free 10879K/12103K, paused 3ms+4ms
01-01 18:35:11.832 1415-1417/system_process D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 729K, 11% free 10889K/12103K, paused 3ms+4ms
01-01 18:35:11.886 1415-1433/system_process I/PackageManager: Removing non-system package:com.video.newfirstworkingapp
01-01 18:35:11.890 1415-1430/system_process I/ActivityManager: Force stopping package com.video.newfirstworkingapp uid=10067
01-01 18:35:11.984 1415-1433/system_process I/PackageManager: Package com.video.newfirstworkingapp codePath changed from /data/app/com.video.newfirstworkingapp-1.apk to /data/app/com.video.newfirstworkingapp-2.apk; Retaining data and using new
01-01 18:35:11.992 1415-1433/system_process I/PackageManager: Running dexopt on: com.video.newfirstworkingapp
01-01 18:35:14.125 15633-15633/? D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: couldn't find field Landroid/app/Notification;.actions
01-01 18:35:14.992 15633-15633/? D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: load 245ms, verify+opt 1076ms
01-01 18:35:15.472 1415-1430/system_process I/ActivityManager: Force stopping package com.video.newfirstworkingapp uid=10067
01-01 18:35:15.472 1415-1433/system_process W/PackageManager: Code path for pkg : com.video.newfirstworkingapp changing from /data/app/com.video.newfirstworkingapp-1.apk to /data/app/com.video.newfirstworkingapp-2.apk
01-01 18:35:15.472 1415-1433/system_process W/PackageManager: Resource path for pkg : com.video.newfirstworkingapp changing from /data/app/com.video.newfirstworkingapp-1.apk to /data/app/com.video.newfirstworkingapp-2.apk
01-01 18:35:15.543 1415-1417/system_process D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 652K, 10% free 10927K/12103K, paused 3ms+7ms
01-01 18:35:15.644 1415-1433/system_process D/PackageManager: New package installed in /data/app/com.video.newfirstworkingapp-2.apk
01-01 18:35:15.742 1415-1433/system_process I/ActivityManager: Force stopping package com.video.newfirstworkingapp uid=10067
01-01 18:35:15.785 1583-1583/com.android.launcher D/dalvikvm: GC_EXPLICIT freed 202K, 8% free 9639K/10439K, paused 3ms+5ms
01-01 18:35:15.914 1624-1624/android.process.acore D/dalvikvm: GC_EXPLICIT freed 250K, 6% free 8022K/8455K, paused 2ms+4ms
01-01 18:35:15.972 1415-1429/system_process D/dalvikvm: GC_EXPLICIT freed 931K, 15% free 10320K/12103K, paused 4ms+5ms
01-01 18:35:15.976 1415-1429/system_process D/PackageManager: generateServicesMap(android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator): 1 services unchanged
01-01 18:35:15.984 1415-1429/system_process D/PackageManager: generateServicesMap(android.content.SyncAdapter): 4 services unchanged
01-01 18:35:15.984 1415-1429/system_process D/BackupManagerService: Received broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED dat=package:com.video.newfirstworkingapp flg=0x10000010 (has extras) }
01-01 18:35:16.019 1415-1429/system_process D/PackageManager: generateServicesMap(android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator): 1 services unchanged
01-01 18:35:16.019 1415-1429/system_process D/PackageManager: generateServicesMap(android.content.SyncAdapter): 4 services unchanged
01-01 18:35:16.043 1415-1429/system_process W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f060000 (t=5 e=0) in package 0 (error -75)
01-01 18:35:16.062 1415-1429/system_process D/BackupManagerService: Received broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.video.newfirstworkingapp flg=0x10000010 (has extras) }
01-01 18:35:16.062 1415-1429/system_process V/BackupManagerService: updatePackageParticipantsLocked: com.video.newfirstworkingapp
01-01 18:35:16.293 1415-1429/system_process D/BackupManagerService: Received broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED dat=package:com.video.newfirstworkingapp flg=0x10000010 (has extras) }
01-01 18:35:16.293 1415-1429/system_process V/BackupManagerService: updatePackageParticipantsLocked: com.video.newfirstworkingapp
01-01 18:35:16.320 2403-2404/com.android.gallery3d D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 438K, 8% free 7802K/8455K, paused 1ms+2ms
01-01 18:35:16.367 1415-1417/system_process D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 575K, 14% free 10417K/12103K, paused 3ms+5ms
01-01 18:35:16.558 1415-1433/system_process D/dalvikvm: GC_EXPLICIT freed 324K, 15% free 10325K/12103K, paused 7ms+6ms
01-01 18:35:16.617 15622-15622/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
01-01 18:35:16.629 15622-15626/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 101K, 83% free 458K/2560K, paused 0ms+0ms
01-01 18:35:16.629 15622-15628/? D/jdwp: Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
01-01 18:35:16.629 15622-15628/? D/dalvikvm: Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
01-01 18:35:16.636 15622-15638/? I/AndroidRuntime: NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
01-01 18:35:17.054 15645-15645/? D/AndroidRuntime: >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
01-01 18:35:17.054 15645-15645/? D/AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is ON
01-01 18:35:17.297 15645-15645/? I/ethernet: Loading ethernet jni class
01-01 18:35:17.367 15645-15645/? D/AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
01-01 18:35:17.375 1415-1609/system_process I/ActivityManager: START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.video.newfirstworkingapp/.MainActivity} from pid 15645
01-01 18:35:17.445 15645-15645/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
01-01 18:35:17.453 15645-15649/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 102K, 81% free 487K/2560K, paused 1ms+0ms
01-01 18:35:17.453 15645-15651/? D/jdwp: Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
01-01 18:35:17.453 15645-15651/? D/dalvikvm: Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
01-01 18:35:17.461 15645-15655/? I/AndroidRuntime: NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
01-01 18:35:17.476 15656-15656/? D/dalvikvm: Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
01-01 18:35:17.480 1415-1415/system_process I/ActivityManager: Start proc com.video.newfirstworkingapp for activity com.video.newfirstworkingapp/.MainActivity: pid=15656 uid=10067 gids={1006}
01-01 18:35:17.504 15656-15662/? D/dalvikvm: Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
01-01 18:35:17.582 15656-15656/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
01-01 18:35:17.582 15656-15656/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
01-01 18:35:17.582 15656-15656/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 19589: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
01-01 18:35:17.582 15656-15656/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
01-01 18:35:17.586 15656-15656/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
01-01 18:35:17.586 15656-15656/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 19593: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
01-01 18:35:17.586 15656-15656/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
01-01 18:35:17.605 1583-1583/com.android.launcher D/OpenGLRenderer: Flushing caches (mode 1)
01-01 18:35:17.644 15656-15656/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onWindowSystemUiVisibilityChanged, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onWindowSystemUiVisibilityChanged
01-01 18:35:17.644 15656-15656/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 19488: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onWindowSystemUiVisibilityChanged (I)V
01-01 18:35:17.644 15656-15656/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0008
01-01 18:35:17.707 15656-15656/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onRtlPropertiesChanged, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.onRtlPropertiesChanged
01-01 18:35:17.707 15656-15656/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 19482: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onRtlPropertiesChanged (I)V
01-01 18:35:17.707 15656-15656/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0007
01-01 18:35:17.711 15656-15656/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
01-01 18:35:17.711 15656-15656/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 440: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
01-01 18:35:17.711 15656-15656/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
01-01 18:35:17.715 15656-15656/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
01-01 18:35:17.715 15656-15656/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 462: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
01-01 18:35:17.715 15656-15656/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
01-01 18:35:17.750 1583-1583/com.android.launcher D/OpenGLRenderer: Flushing caches (mode 0)
01-01 18:35:17.785 15656-15656/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable
01-01 18:35:17.785 15656-15656/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 403: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
01-01 18:35:17.785 15656-15656/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
01-01 18:35:17.785 15656-15656/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawableForDensity
01-01 18:35:17.785 15656-15656/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 405: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
01-01 18:35:17.785 15656-15656/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
01-01 18:35:17.808 15656-15657/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 238K, 5% free 7910K/8263K, paused 3ms+3ms
01-01 18:35:17.824 15656-15656/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.resolveLayoutDirection, referenced from method android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams.resolveLayoutDirection
01-01 18:35:17.824 15656-15656/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 19424: Landroid/view/ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams;.resolveLayoutDirection (I)V
01-01 18:35:17.828 15656-15656/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0002
01-01 18:35:17.836 1233-1233/? I/CameraService: Opening camera 0
01-01 18:35:17.836 1233-1233/? I/CameraHardwareSec: int android::HAL_camera_device_open(const hw_module_t*, const char*, hw_device_t**): open camera 0
01-01 18:35:17.836 1233-1233/? I/SecCamera: Name of input channel[0] is ov3640
01-01 18:35:17.855 1233-1233/? I/SecCamera: Name of input channel[0] is ov3640
01-01 18:35:17.855 1233-1233/? I/SecCamera: initCamera : initialized
01-01 18:35:17.855 1233-1233/? I/SecCamera: Name of input channel[0] is ov3640
01-01 18:35:17.855 1233-1233/? D/CameraHardwareSec: getPreviewMaxSize return 640,480 
01-01 18:35:17.855 1233-1233/? D/CameraHardwareSec: getSnapshotMaxSize return 640,480 
01-01 18:35:17.855 1233-1233/? I/CameraHardwareSec: int android::HAL_camera_device_open(const hw_module_t*, const char*, hw_device_t**): opened camera 0 (0x767998)
01-01 18:35:17.859 1233-15672/? I/CameraHardwareSec: int android::CameraHardwareSec::previewThreadWrapper(): starting
01-01 18:35:17.859 1233-15672/? I/CameraHardwareSec: int android::CameraHardwareSec::previewThreadWrapper(): calling mSecCamera->stopPreview() and waiting
01-01 18:35:17.859 1233-15672/? W/SecCamera: int android::SecCamera::stopPreview(): doing nothing because m_flag_camera_start is zero
01-01 18:35:17.863 1233-1233/? I/AwesomePlayer: setDataSource_l('/system/media/audio/ui/camera_click.ogg')
01-01 18:35:17.875 1233-1233/? I/AwesomePlayer: setDataSource_l('/system/media/audio/ui/VideoRecord.ogg')
01-01 18:35:17.894 15656-15656/? D/ERROR: get camera
01-01 18:35:17.894 15656-15656/? D/ERROR: ABLE TO PREVIEW camera
01-01 18:35:17.941 15656-15656/? D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
01-01 18:35:17.945 15656-15656/? D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
01-01 18:35:17.953 15656-15656/? D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
01-01 18:35:17.957 15656-15656/? D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
01-01 18:35:18.039 15656-15656/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
01-01 18:35:18.140 1415-1445/system_process I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.video.newfirstworkingapp/.MainActivity: +704ms
```

Logcat after Connect button is clicked

```
1-01 18:35:30.965 1487-1489/com.android.systemui D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 202K, 7% free 8406K/9031K, paused 2ms+2ms
01-01 18:35:30.988 1487-1487/com.android.systemui D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 207K, 10% free 8198K/9031K, paused 23ms
01-01 18:35:31.074 1487-1487/com.android.systemui D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 311K, 10% free 8198K/9031K, paused 19ms
01-01 18:35:31.566 2417-2419/com.android.vending D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 370K, 8% free 8093K/8775K, paused 2ms+2ms
01-01 18:35:31.652 2417-2417/com.android.vending D/Finsky: [1] 5.onFinished: Installation state replication succeeded.
01-01 18:35:38.265 1415-1573/system_process I/ActivityManager: START {cmp=com.video.newfirstworkingapp/.CameraView} from pid 15656
01-01 18:35:38.273 1233-1407/? D/AudioHardware: AudioHardware pcm playback is exiting standby.
01-01 18:35:38.273 1233-1407/? D/AudioHardware: openPcmOut_l() mPcmOpenCnt: 0
01-01 18:35:38.304 15656-15656/com.video.newfirstworkingapp D/ERROR: Able to go next Class
01-01 18:35:38.316 15656-15656/com.video.newfirstworkingapp D/dalvikvm: newInstance failed: no <init>()
01-01 18:35:38.316 15656-15656/com.video.newfirstworkingapp D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
01-01 18:35:38.316 15656-15656/com.video.newfirstworkingapp W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a451f8)
01-01 18:35:38.320 15656-15656/com.video.newfirstworkingapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.video.newfirstworkingapp/com.video.newfirstworkingapp.CameraView}: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.video.newfirstworkingapp.CameraView; no empty constructor
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1880)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
                                                                                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.video.newfirstworkingapp.CameraView; no empty constructor
                                                                                  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
                                                                                  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
                                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1871)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551) 
                                                                                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
01-01 18:35:38.340 1415-1426/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.video.newfirstworkingapp/.CameraView
01-01 18:35:38.340 1415-1426/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.video.newfirstworkingapp/.MainActivity
01-01 18:35:38.386 1415-1417/system_process D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 538K, 14% free 10459K/12103K, paused 3ms+4ms
01-01 18:35:38.840 1415-1429/system_process W/ActivityManager: Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{414ef840 com.video.newfirstworkingapp/.CameraView}
01-01 18:35:41.285 1233-1407/? D/AudioHardware: AudioHardware pcm playback is going to standby.
01-01 18:35:41.285 1233-1407/? D/AudioHardware: closePcmOut_l() mPcmOpenCnt: 1
01-01 18:35:49.031 1415-1429/system_process W/ActivityManager: Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{413ef6b8 com.video.newfirstworkingapp/.MainActivity}
01-01 18:35:49.031 1415-1429/system_process W/ActivityManager: Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{414ef840 com.video.newfirstworkingapp/.CameraView}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to start an activity, but `CameraView` isn't an activity, here:

```
            Intent changePageIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,CameraView.class);
            startActivity(changePageIntent);
```

If you want an activity holding a `SurfaceView` , you should create a new class extending Activity and implement your `SurfaceView` there.